# Is the predicative proper in this example?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, adverbs

> I object to praises that are too **abundant** and too **often**.

1. Does the meaning of *abundant* fit here?
2. *Often* is an adverb, so can it be used as a predicative which is
   usually adjective or noun?

Comment: I object to pluralising *praise* in this construction.

Comment: Yeah better make it simply *I object to praise that is...* in this sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Why? As a noun, praise is countable.

Comment: @Tim: It's like *I don't like anchovies/sprouts/whatever*. I can't explain exactly why - it just doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: In this sense, *praise* is uncountable. You would say "I have nothing but praise for you", and "praises" sounds quite funny here. If you said "I have nothing but compliments for you", you would use the plural because *compliment* is always countable.

Comment: @Peter: Do praise and compliment have the same meaning? Why is compliment always countable, while praise isn't?

Comment: @Tim: The meaning isn't quite the same, but pretty close. If you're asking me to say why praise isn't always a count noun, while compliment always is, I can't tell you--I don't know why English works the way it does. I can refer you to a [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/praise) that agrees with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Abundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abundant)* fits; it means *present in great quantity; more than adequate; oversufficient*.

*Often* does not fit; an independent adverb may not be the sole predicate of a clause.  You could make the adverb modify an adjective (such as *given*) to get rid of the grammatical inconsistency:

> I object to praise that is too abundant and too often given.

Or you could replace the adverb with an adjective:

> I object to praise that is too abundant and too frequent.

However, all that said, there are many more words in the sentence than is necessary.  For instance, *abundant* includes a good bit of *frequent*, so you could easily remove the last three or four words; also, *[noun] that is too [adj]* can often be simplified to *over-[adj] [noun]*.  *I object to* sounds a little more judgmental than necessary: I would use *I dislike*.  So the sentence now looks like this:

> I dislike overabundant praise.

That sounds much better than the original.

Comment: I think *praises that are too abundant* sounds like something from a bad software translator. The natural phrasing is *overabundant praise*, or the vastly more common [undue praise](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undue+praise%2Coverabundant+praise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Fumble: If you downvoted, would you check the answer again?  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Downvote reversed. I particularly like your point that *abundant* carries much of the sense of *frequent*. I knew there was something wrong with OP's *and too often*, but I thought this was somehow connected to the pluralised *praises* which I also didn't like. I'm now sure you've hit the nail on the head - *abundant* implies quantity *and* frequency.